# How do i lay out my buttons so they will go from top left to bottom right (filling first row then second)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

So I have a JPanel filled whit JButtons and only Jbuttons:[image: Like this]

How do I make it so when only button 1 and button 20 are Visible so the button layout becomes [image: Like this]
and if I were to have Jbuuton 15 Visible it would come in between JButton 1 and 20.

I'm trying to just make it anchor to the top and left and set the spacing to 0 but it does this:[image: What is happening for me]

I can't really give a code as it is made in NetBeans generated code and the program setting buttons to visible are depending on a lot of other stuff so making it independent would take a lot of time.

Edit:
Using a method to add the JButtons to a grid via a method
in my case

```
public static void RedoGridLayout(){
    GridLayout UpgradesLayout = new GridLayout(0,5);
    CookieclickerGUI.Panel_Upgrade.setLayout(UpgradesLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i<upgrades.size(); i++){
        Upgrades upgrade = upgrades.get(i);
        JButton Button = upgrade.getJButton();
        if(Button.isVisible()){
            CookieclickerGUI.Panel_Upgrade.add(Button);
            System.out.println("Added...\n" + Button + "\nButton to the grid");
        }
    }
}
```

this how ever adds the button in a grid at the **Bottom** and not the top, so if you want to see the buttons you need to scroll down.

**EDIT 2:***
The buttons got placed at the bottom as the other buttons were still in the panel (ofc they were) so by doing `.removeAll();` before placed the buttons at the top left but extended to fit the whole panel. that I fixed by adding all buttons that were `!.isvisible()` after making the button correct shape.

Comment: Use a GridLayout and re-lay out components when/if one is removed. Fill the empty spots with empty JLabels. The details will depend on your code, and so you should consider posting a valid [mcve] with your question.

Comment: So I should do something like a for-loop to check all buttons in order to see if they are visible whit if (Button.isvisible()) and then add them to the grid layout if they are visible?

buttons represent Upgrades in an incremental game I'm making (copycat of Cookie Clicker) so I need to check them each second and making me re-add them.

On second thought, I can redo the layout each time a button is toggled visible or invisible running the method to redo the GridLayout when I buy the upgrade and when I manage to achieve the requirement to unlock another.

Comment: I have no idea what *specifically* you should do. Again, please consider creating and posting a [mcve], a program that we can compile, and run and that shows your problem. This is not your whole program, but a new one created just to illustrate the problem for us, small enough to be posted as code-formatted text with your question.

Comment: The GridLayout is pretty much all I needed but got a new problem. it is in the bottom of the panel which is inside of a scroll panel making me have to scroll thru emptiness to get to the buttons. is that why I should fill it whit labels empty JLables?

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character which makes your code hard to read since the forum highlights your variable names the same as class names. Some of your variable are correct, others are not. Be consistent and follow Java convention.

Comment: `got a new problem` - and yet you still haven't posted an "MCVE", ` making me have to scroll thru emptiness to get to the buttons` - we have no idea why you have emptiness on your panel. The GridLayout will always position the buttons at the top of the panel. Without the "MCVE" we can't guess what you are doing. I also see a problem in that you are using a "static" method to layout your buttons. A static method like that is almost always a sign or improper program design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer to my Question was GridLayout.
it put my buttons in the Grid that I wanted.

The solution to the grid being placed at the bottom was because a simple mistake by me adding the grid to the layout when it contained a lot of buttons being set to `.setvisible(false);` so the program placed it after all buttons. this was fixed by a simple `.removeAll();` removing all JComponents that were stored in it.

**Note** that I stored all my JComponents in a JButton array as I only had buttons and later did a for loop running thru the array checking if it was visible or not and if it was it got added to the grid.